# How to disable next button in ui bootstrap pagination?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I am trying to create pagination in my page and using pagination control. Everything works fine, but only doubt is how to manually disable next button here

```
<pagination   
    total-items="totalItems" 
    items-per-page= "itemsPerPage"
    ng-model="currentPage" 
    class="pagination-sm"  
    page="currentPage"
    max-size= "maxSize"
    ng-change="pageChanged(currentPage)">
</pagination>
```

In my controller-

```
$scope.currentPage=1;
$scope.itemsPerPage = 5;
$scope.maxSize = 2;
$scope.numberofrows =5;

 $scope.fetchResult =function(startingId){
                  if(startingId ==undefined){
                      $scope.StartingId = ''; 
                  }
                  else{
                      $scope.StartingId= startingId ; 
                  }
                  Api.customerReq.queryProductbyperiod({ productId : $scope.customerProduct , productperiod :$scope.customerPeriod,startingid: $scope.StartingId,numberofrows:$scope.numberofrows}).$promise.then(function(result) {
                        if(result){
                            if(result&&result.length==0){
                                // error alert 
                                }
                            $scope.customerResult = result;
                            if($scope.currentPage==1){
                             $scope.NextStartingId = result[5].id;
                             // on landing page storing last stringId for the next request to cassandra since row num requested as 6.
                            }
                            else{
                            $scope.NextStartingId = result[4].id;  // rest of the page, row num requested as 5.
                            }

                    $scope.previousStartingId=$scope.NextStartingId; 
                            if($scope.currentPage== 1){ 
                                $scope.totalItems= result.length;
                            }
$scope . pageChanged = function (page) {
    if (page > $scope . count)
    {
        $scope . count ++;
        //  temp = page;
        $scope . nextPage();
    } else
    {
        $scope . count = page;
        $scope . prevPage();
    }
};

              $scope.prevPage = function() {
                  if($scope.currentPage ==1){
                         $scope.previousStartingId = '';
                        }
                  $scope.fetchResult($scope.previousStartingId);
                  if($scope.currentpage>1)
                       $scope.totalItems -=5;

              };
             $scope.nextPage = function() {
                 if($scope.currentPage!=1){
                     $scope.numberofrows =5;

                 }                               
                 $scope.fetchResult($scope.NextStartingId);

                  $scope.totalItems +=5;     
                  };
```

Here calling next and previous page on each pagechange. What I am missing or how to manually disable nextlink? or how datepicker will work in this situation?

Yes I do api request each time I hit next or prev button, as cassandra has very limited support to pagination. So each time am querying with stored stringId to filter the result as they are storing in Cassandra table as ordered list. So it is more like server side pagination am doing here.

Comment: how do you use '$scope.numberofrows =5;' ?

Comment: do you mean you want 'Next' button to be always disabled, no matter what?

Comment: Since i always know there is more data is available because i am querying 6 rows at first time, and then 5 for rest of the pages, and itemperpage is 5. Suppose i have total 23 rows available in the server, So with my logic on landing page i will get 6 rows , means (1st page=5 rows) and for 2nd page again i will query with number of rows =5, So on 5th request once all 23 result shown there i have to disable my next button

Answer (score 0):

UI boortstrap will automatically disable next link if there are no pages to show. You don't need to use `ng-change` for disabling pagination items. I't supposed for other handlers if you need them, for example confirmation or ajax request.
You can check by following formula:

```
totalItems / temsPerPage - maxSize
```